Max function with BARON, SCIP,
I read that solvers like BARON, SCIP don't allow the use of the $max(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ function. What might be the reason for this?
One might say, because the $max$ function can be expressed by using e.g. the $abs$ function. Is this the only reason?

It's for no particular technical reason, but maybe there's simply little user need for it. Our solver for instance (Octeract Engine) solves the same types of problems as the ones you mentioned to proven global optimality and we support $\min(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),...)$ and $\max(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),...)$.
There were a few tricks we came up with to make it perform properly, but to be honest nothing I wouldn't expect a professional solver developer to have trouble figuring out.
